# NoReverseMatch at /posts/

Tags: python, django, exception, django-templates, django-views

Just quick info I'm a beginner in python and django.

Here is an issue:

I'm trying to create simple blog app with django, I've created all whats needed and I'm able to render one of my main pages however when I try to access posts page(to be able to view current posts) I receive the following error:

```
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://localhost:8000/posts/
Django Version: 2.0.2
Exception Type: NoReverseMatch
Exception Value:    
Reverse for 'post' not found. 'post' is not a valid view function or pattern name.
```

I'm not sure why I receive this error as I have posts view function written and accessible, here are my files:

**my_blog/urls.py**

```
"""Defines URL patterns for my_blog."""

from django.conf.urls import  url

from . import views

#needed app name
app_name='my_blog'
urlpatterns=[
    #Homepage
    url(r'^$',views.home,name='home'),
    # Show all posts.
    url(r'^posts/$', views.posts, name='posts'),
```

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.

class BlogPost(models.Model):
    """Post that can be viewed"""
    title=models.CharField(max_length=200)
    text=models.TextField()
    date_added=models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        """Return a string representation of the model."""
        if len(self.text)<50:
            return self.text
        else:
            return self.text[:50] + "..."
```

**views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from .models import BlogPost
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect



# Create your views here.

def home(request):
    """The home page for Learning Log"""
    return render(request,'my_blog/home.html')


def posts (request):
    """Show all posts."""
    posts=BlogPost.objects.order_by('date_added')
    context={'posts':posts}
    return  render(request, 'my_blog/posts.html', context)
```

*HTML pages:*

**home.html**

```
{%extends "my_blog/base.html"%}

{%block content%}
<html>
<p align="center">Welcome to my Blog</p>

</body>
</html>

{%endblock content%}
```

**base.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>My Blog</title>
</head>
<body bgcolor="#85C1E9">
<p>
    <a href="{%url 'my_blog:home'%}">Home</a> -
    <a href="{%url 'my_blog:posts'%}">Posts</a>
</p>

{%block content%}{%endblock content%}

</body>
</html>
```

**posts.html**

```
{%extends "my_blog/base.html"%}


{%block content%}

<p>Posts</p>

<ul>
    {%for post in posts%}
    <li><a href="{%url 'my_blog:post' post.id%}">{{post}}</a> </li>
    {%empty%}
        <li>No posts have been added yet.</li>
    {%endfor%}
</ul>
{%endblock content%}
```

Thanks in advance for assistance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your template you have:

```
{% url 'my_blog:post' post.id %}
```

This gives an error because you have not yet defined a URL pattern in `my_blog/urls.py` with `name="post"`.

Answer (score 1):

The view name that you are looking up in your template does not match the name defined in your urls.py.  You need to make

**urls.py**

```
    url(r'^posts/$', views.posts, name='posts'),
```

and 
**posts.html**

```
<li><a href="{%url 'my_blog:post' post.id%}">{{post}}</a> </li>
```

match by either adding an `s` in `posts,html` or remove the `s` in `urls.py`

**Edit**

Looking a little deeper... You need to define your detail view (`post` with a parameter) in `views.py`.  And add a corresponding entry in `urls.py`  Then undo the change I recommended earlier.

You should also consider renaming your views from `posts` and `post` to something like `post_list` and `post_detail`

Comment: Thanks @Alan , I did as you advised and now I have this:Reverse for 'posts' with arguments '(1,)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['posts/$']